# Initializing non-primitive type variables using LDFLAGS in GoLang

Tags: go

I'm trying to initialize a variable in build time, using *ldflags* option in *go build*.

This code works fine:

```
var version

func printVersion() {
    fmt.Printf(version) // prints the corresponding value
}
```

```bash
go build -ldflags="-X $(ROOT)/pkg/info.version=123"
```

But I can't seem to find a way to initialize a variable of my own-defined struct. I mean, this doesn't seem to work:

```
type VersionInfo struct {
    version string
}

var versionInfo VersionInfo

func printVersion() {
    fmt.Printf(versionInfo.version)
}
```

```bash
go build -ldflags="-X $(ROOT)/pkg/info.versionInfo.version=123"
```

I couldn't find anything in official docs referring to this issue. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the documentation, it seems it's not possible to do that via the linker flags. The variable must be of type `string`.

> -X importpath.name=value
> Set the value of the string variable in importpath named name to value.
> This is only effective if the variable is declared in the source code either uninitialized
> or initialized to a constant string expression. -X will not work if the initializer makes
> a function call or refers to other variables.
> Note that before Go 1.5 this option took two separate arguments.

source: https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/link

Comment: You could however pass JSON to the linker and parse it into any type at runtime.